# ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestAlertDialog() returns null for android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, robolectric

Is there any workaround that will allow us to test `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` in **Robolectric**?

```
   someActivity.findViewById(R.id.alet_btn).performClick();
   AlertDialog alert = ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestAlertDialog();
   ShadowAlertDialog shadowAlertDialog = Shadows.shadowOf(alert);
   assertThat(shadowAlertDialog.getTitle()).isEqualTo("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
    List shownDialogs = ShadowAlertDialog.getShownDialogs();
    if (shownDialogs.get(0) instanceof AlertDialog) {
    AlertDialog dialog = (android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog) shownDialogs.get(0);
    assertThat(dialog).isShowing();
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).performClick();
    }
```

or

```
    if (ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestDialog() instanceof AlertDialog) {
        AlertDialog dialog = (android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog) ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestDialog();
        assertThat(dialog).isShowing();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
    }
```

It allows you to click the buttons, but can't verify title or message AFAIK.